# Android: Need faster way to display RGB565 bitmap from byte array

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I have an RGB565 byte array which I display on my Canvas like this:

```
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data); // data is my array
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
    // then I display the bitmap on my SurfaceView
```

I can see this procedure is rather slow on my phone. Can I do faster than that, I just need to display this byte RGB565 array on my canvas. My phone doesn't have graphic acelerator so openGL probably won't help..

Comment: Why is the performance a problem?  Are you doing this many times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a detailed answer, but if you need serious performance with the bitmaps, I'd look at doing it in the NDK.  I've dabbled with this a bit and its pretty good.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Look at the plasma example.  We basically started with that and built our solution.

Beyond that, I'd suggest not creating a new bitmap on each run.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I did create a new bitmap on each run. As soon as I've started using a single bitmap performance increased very very much. I'm yet to look into the plasma solution you've suggested

Comment: With the approach from the plasma sample it's even faster, thanks